# Flask 404 Not found after POST request on MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a MongoDB community running on my MacOS.
I want to connect, and send data, from it to a Flask server (I don't know if Flask server is the right name, I'm sorry about that) so I can get and add data to it.

Database name is : "USERS" while its collection is "user". (this is my first time doing this).

This is my code :

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine


app=Flask(__name__)

database_name="USERS"
DB_URI ="mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false"
app.config["MONGODB_HOST"]=DB_URI

db=MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)

class User(db.Document):
    user_id= db.IntField()
    user_name=db.StringField()
    user_bio=db.StringField()

    def to_json(self):
        #convert this document to JSON
        return {
            "user_id" : self.user_id,
            "user_name" : self.user_name,
            "user_bio" : self.user_bio
        }

@app.route("http://127.0.0.1:5000/USERS/db_populate",methods=['POST'])
def db_populate():
    user1=User(user_id=1,user_name="Marco", user_bio="Hi!")
    user2=User(user_id=2,user_name="Francesca", user_bio="What a weird program!")
    user1.save()
    user2.save()
    return make_response("",201)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm sure DB_URI is correct.
Generic user must have : id, name and bio.

After run this command : `http POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/USERS/db_populate` I have the following output :

```
mac.fede@Ahoga ~ % http POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/USERS/db_populate
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Length: 86
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2021 16:40:12 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.9.1

{
    "message": "Not foundhttp://127.0.0.1:5000/USERS/db_populate",
    "status": 404
}
```

I'm trying to find the right path because I'm sure that some paths aren't correct, what do you think?

EDIT : Solved, I was running the wrong server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you try:

```
@app.route("/USERS/db_populate",methods=['POST']) ?
```

Comment: I already tried but doesn't work. Is The question mark at the end of the sentence an error ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use only paths for the app.route().

Thus change

```
@app.route("http://127.0.0.1:5000/USERS/db_populate",methods=['POST'])
```

to

```
@app.route("/USERS/db_populate",methods=['POST'])
```

also to follow the gerneral naming conventions for path names only lowercase letters should be used, so

```
@app.route("/users/db_populate",methods=['POST'])
```

would be even better. Using uppercase letters is possible but it might lead to confusion and errors later on when people try to reference ur endpoint using lowercase letters.

Comment: Ok thank you, I read on the internet that I need also to use lowercase while writing paths, is it right?

Comment: I adjusted my answer to also consider naming convetions. You don't need to use lowercase letters but you should, it is a convention.